# Copy one xml document to another using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

this is my situation:

I have two org.w3c.dom.Document created from two xml files. What I want to obtain is brand new Document containing all the data of the two xml Document.

Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do ? Mix the data, or just paste the two trees one after another ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- create a new document
- create a new root called **newRoot**
- add the first document root as child of **newRoot**
- add the second document root as child of **newRoot**